# Change data in multi-index Groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to change data in the below Groupby object, to set the value of

```
dff=pd.DataFrame({'country':['US','US','UK','UK','FR','FR'],'type':['A','B']*3,'sales':[100,200,100,100,50,10]})
grouped=dff.groupby(['country','type'])['sales'].sum()

grouped.loc['US']=dff.groupby('type')['sales'].sum()

print(grouped)
```

but it get nan for the rows I tried to change:

[image]

Any help here will be awesome :)
Thanks

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
grouped['US'] = dff.groupby('type')['sales'].sum()
```

Output:

```
country  type
FR       A        50
         B        10
UK       A       100
         B       100
US       A       250
         B       310
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding value

```
grouped.loc['US']=dff.groupby('type')['sales'].sum().values
grouped
Out[41]: 
country  type
FR       A        50
         B        10
UK       A       100
         B       100
US       A       250
         B       310
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```